# Settings up Apache proxy server on AWS EC2 apache for NodeJS app

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2, mod-proxy

I've managed to install SSL certificates and run the server on https successfully, now I need to forward all the incoming requests to NodeJS app, but I can't make it work.

So I'm confused between these three `conf` files:

`/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` -
`/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` - `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd-le-ssl.conf`

I'm pretty new in apache and aws so don't really know which one actually needs to be modified and what should I add in it?
currently this is what I have changed in `httpd.conf` file:

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ServerName "MyDOMAIN.net"
    ServerAlias "www.MyDOMAIN.net"

ProxyPreserveHost On

ProxyPass / https://localhost:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:3000/

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =MyDOMAIN.net [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.MyDOMAIN.net
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

in `ssl.conf` file, I've just added:

```
SSLEngine on
SSLProxyEngine on
```

and `httpd-le-ssl.conf` content:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ServerName "MyDOMAIN.net"
    ServerAlias "www.MyDOMAIN.net"

   # SSLEngine on
   # ProxyPreserveHost On
   # ProxyPass / https://localhost:3000/
   # ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:3000/

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/MyDOMAIN.net/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/MyDOMAIN.net/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

what I get now when executing a call to my node end-point is a 404 error.

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

and this is the content of `app.js`:

```
const express = require('express')
const https = require('https')
const fs = require('fs')
const logger = require('./middleware/logger')
const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

require('./startup/loggin')()
require('./startup/routes')(app)
require('./startup/database').connect()
require('./startup/config')()
require('./startup/validation')()

https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/MyDOMAIN.net/privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/MyDOMAIN.net/fullchain.pem')
}, app)
.listen(port, logger.log('info', `Listening to port ${port}...`))
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below line in your httpd-le-ssl.conf file

SSLProxyEngine on

Also uncomment below lines in httpd-le-ssl.conf file because you are using ssh so this will work from 443 virtual host

`SSLEngine on`
`ProxyPreserveHost On`
`ProxyPass / https://localhost:3000/`
`ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:3000/`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make the changes in the httpd file and nowhere else inorder to proxy to the node server.

paste this in end
—

```
ProxyPass /node http://localhost:3000/

LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

—